# Approach to measuring end-to-end latency from a sales transaction to a stock level in a database

Tags: algorithm, apache-kafka

I have a system in which sales transactions are written to a Kafka topic in real time.  One of the consumers of this data is an *aggregator* program which maintains a database of stock quantities for all locations, in real time; it will consume data from multiple other sources as well.  For example, when a product is sold from a store, the aggregator will reduce the quantity of that product in that store by the quantity sold.

This aggregator's database will be presented via an API to allow applications to check stock availability (the *inventory*) in any store in real time.

> (Note for context - yes, there is an ERP behind all this which does a lot more; the purpose of this inventory API is to consume data from multiple sources, including the ERP and the ERP's data feeds, and potentially other ERPs in future, to give a single global information source for this singular purpose).

What I want to do is to measure the *end-to-end latency*: how long it takes from a sales transaction being written to the topic, to being processed by the aggregator (not just read from the topic).  This will give an indicator of how far behind real-time the inventory database is.

The sales transaction topic will probably be partitioned, so the transactions may not arrive in order.

So far I have thought of two methods.

#### Method 1 - measure latency via stock level changes

Here, the sales producer injects a special "measurement" sale each minute, for an invalid location like "SKU 0 in branch 0".  The sale quantity would be based on the time of day, using a numerical sequence of some kind.  A program would then poll the inventory API, or directly read the database, to check for changes in the level.  When it changes, the magnitude of the change will indicate the time of the originating transaction.  The difference between then and now gives us the latency.

**Problem:** If multiple transactions are queued and are then later all processed together, the change in inventory value will be the sum of the queued transactions, giving a false reading.

To solve this, the sequence of numbers would have to be chosen such that when they are added together, we can always determine *which was the lowest number*, giving us the oldest transaction and therefore the latency.

We could use powers of 2 for this, so the lowest bit set would indicate the earliest transaction time.  Our sequence would have to reset every 30 or 60 minutes and we'd have to cope with wraparound and lots of edge cases.

Assuming we can solve the wraparound problem and that a maximum measurable latency of, say, 20 minutes is OK (after which we just say it's "too high"), then with this method, it does not matter whether transactions are processed out of sequence or split into partitions.

This method gives a "true" picture of the end-to-end latency, in that it's measuring the point at which the database has actually been updated.

#### Method 2 - measure latency via special timestamp record

Instead of injecting measurement sales records, we use a timestamp which the producer is adding to the raw data.  This timestamp is just the time at which the producer transmitted this record.

The aggregator would maintain a measurement of the most recently seen timestamp.  The difference between that and the current time would give the latency.

**Problem:** If transactions are not processed in order, the latency measurement will be unstable, because it relies on the timestamps arriving in sequence.

To solve this, the aggregator would not just output the last timestamp it saw, but instead would output the oldest timestamp it had seen in the past minute across all of its threads (assuming multiple threads potentially reading from multiple partitions).  This would give a less "lumpy" view.

This method gives an approximate picture of the end-to-end latency, since it's measuring the point at which the aggregator receives the sales record, not the point at which the database has been updated.

#### The questions

1. Is one method more likely to get usable results than the other?
2. For method 1, is there a sequence of numbers which would be more efficient than powers of 2 in allowing us to work out the earliest value when multiple ones arrive at once, requiring fewer bits so that the time before sequence reset would be longer?
3. Would method 1 have the same problem of "lumpy" data as method 2, in the case of a large number of partitions or data arriving out of order?
4. Given that method 2 seems simpler, is the method of smoothing out the lumps in the measurement a plausible one?